Crelander YG14D - Dual Goodix Touchscreens config? Driver Issue?
Edit Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
KERNEL 6.9.3-060903-GENERIC
Updated to 6.9.3 in hopes it solved the issue but whatever version is fine at end the day.
I bought yet another random aliexpress oddity and I feel like I'm halfway there in getting the dual touch screens to work.
[    0.702538] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    4.392654] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.392699] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.406502] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: ID 9271, version: 1044
[    4.412267] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-2/i2c-GDIX1002:00/input/input7
[    4.429690] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.430473] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.432976] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.456022] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.478426] i2c i2c-6: 1/2 memory slots populated (from DMI)
[    4.566280] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.588153] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.609562] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: I2C communication failure: -121
[    4.609709] Goodix-TS: probe of i2c-GDIX1002:01 failed with error -121

They both appear to be on the same i2c bus. The Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00 bottom screen's touch will appear as a Goodix device which I can map-to-output of the bottom monitor. Get our xinput devices, and find the ID of our touchscreen.
xinput list
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse Consumer Control               id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard System Control  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard Consumer Control    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4G Mouse System Control                 id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4G Mouse Consumer Control               id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]

Our touchscreen is id=15
Run xrandr to get our monitor names.
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2560, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1280+0+0 inverted (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 222mm x 148mm
   1920x1280     60.00*+  48.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1280+0+1280 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 222mm x 148mm
   1920x1280     60.00*+  48.00  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


xinput map-to-output 15 DP-1
Now the bottom touch screen is usable.
The issue now is that the other Goodix device fails to load per dmesg. Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01
dmesg | grep -i i2c
[    0.702538] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    4.392654] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.392699] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.406502] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: ID 9271, version: 1044
[    4.412267] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-2/i2c-GDIX1002:00/input/input7
[    4.429690] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.430473] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.432976] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.456022] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.478426] i2c i2c-6: 1/2 memory slots populated (from DMI)
[    4.566280] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.588153] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: Error reading 1 bytes from 0x8140: -121
[    4.609562] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:01: I2C communication failure: -121
[    4.609709] Goodix-TS: probe of i2c-GDIX1002:01 failed with error -121

Is this a limitation of the Goodix Driver or is there configuration that could get that second touch screen working?
I tried other drivers, as well evtest never registers input on any event while tapping the top screen which makes sense.
I suspect it may be a bug, or perhaps just a scenario not imagined in the original driver. Could a new instance of the driver solve that?
I greatly appreciate any assistance. I feel like all the drivers are here, I'm just one step away. Been a lot of research so far but I've just hit a block.
System info:
https://pastebin.com/Y7usBGvE

Missing critical details. Ubuntu version and kernel version. Please edit the question and add this info.
